# Make Adobe PDF Embed API work in NextJS (maybe by disabling SSR)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-redux, server-side-rendering

Recently, I made a web app in React, in which one of the pages renders a PDF file using Adobe's PDF Embed API, it works fine with React. But when I migrated from Create React App to NextJS, it broke down, where rest of the page components are working perfectly working fine, except for the renderer.

I need to get that API to work for its rich and functional viewer.

I thought this was a server side rendering problem, I tried to solve it by using a Higher Order Component and disabling SSR in the NextJS dynamic imports but still, I can't get it to work. Here's the code for the original page in NextJS (everything renders and works fine except for the renderer, an empty div is rendered but the content which has to fill it and comes from the API is not there):

***<sub>/pages/notes/[id].tsx</sub>***

```
import { Flex, Heading, HStack, Link, Stack, Text, useColorMode, VStack } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import ReactGA from "react-ga4";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { toast } from "react-hot-toast";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Loader from "../../components/Layout/Loader";
import ViewSDKClient from "../../others/ViewSDKClient";
import { getNotes } from "../../redux/actions/subject";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const Notes = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { colorMode } = useColorMode();

  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = router.query;

  const { notes, error, loading } = useSelector((state: any) => state.subjects);
  document.title = notes ? (notes.title + " - CollegeNotes") : "Loading - CollegeNotes";

  useEffect(() => {
    ReactGA.send({ hitType: "pageview", page: document.title + window.location.pathname });
  }, [notes])

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getNotes(id) as any);
  }, [dispatch, id]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      toast.error(error);
      dispatch({ type: "clearError" });
    }
  }, [error, dispatch]);

  const loadPDF = () => {
    const viewSDKClient = new ViewSDKClient();
    viewSDKClient.ready().then(() => {
      viewSDKClient.previewFile(
        "pdf-div",
        {
          embedMode: window.innerWidth > 800 ? "SIZED_CONTAINER" : "FULL_WINDOW",
          showAnnotationTools: false,
          showPageControls: true,
          showDownloadPDF: false,
          showPrintPDF: false,
        },
        
        notes.document.url,
        notes.title
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {loading || !notes ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <Flex
          minH={"100vh"}
          width={"100%"}
          direction={"row"}
          justifyContent={"space-around"}
        >
          <Stack
            height={"100%"}
            marginX={"3"}
            marginY={["8", "10", "12", "12", "14"]}
            width={"container.md"}
          >
            <Heading
              size={["xs", "sm"]}
              fontFamily={"Roboto Condensed"}
              children={notes.subject}
              textTransform={"uppercase"}
              paddingBottom={"2px"}
              borderBottom={"3px solid"}
              display={"inline"}
              width={"fit-content"}
            />

            <Heading
              as={"h1"}
              paddingTop={["1", "2"]}
              children={notes.title}
              fontFamily={"Source Serif Pro"}
              fontWeight={"extrabold"}
              size={["2xl", "3xl"]}
            />

            <HStack fontSize={"13px"}>
              <Text fontFamily={"Inter"} children={"Contributed by: "} />
              
              <Link
                target={"_blank"}
                fontFamily={"Inter"}
                color={ colorMode === "light" ? "teal.600" : "teal.300"}
                href={notes.contributorSocial}
              >
                {notes.contributor}
              </Link>
            </HStack>
            

            <Text
              fontSize={"md"}
              fontFamily={"Lusitana"}
              paddingTop={["4", "7"]}
              paddingBottom={["1", "3"]}
              children={notes.description}
            />

            <VStack width={"100%"}>
              <Flex
                id="pdf-div"
                height={"98vh"}
                onLoad={loadPDF()!}
              />
            </VStack>
          </Stack>
        </Flex>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Notes;
```